# using array values as where clause in a query and incrementing query's number php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

I have an array of ids sent by GET method to another page, in that page I'm exploding on "," and saving the $_GET values in an array, my objective is to use each id in the array in the same query, where the difference between each query will be only where id= the id retrieved from the array, and then get a column name called amount and add it with other amounts of other ids, how can I achieve this? Can I loop on query's variable name? Like increment $sql.$i?

My current query:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($claimID);++$i) {
$sql="SELECT ... and subscriptions.subscription_Id=".$claimID[$i]; } // should i try to figure out a way to increment $sql with $i ?
```

and then

```
$resultSql = $conn->query($sql); // I should loop somehow
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSql);
```

After this I want to get each column "amount" selected by all queries on different ids and + them, can I get some tips/suggestions please?

Comment: are you trying to fetch all data for each id or any count of records for each id ?

Comment: If you have a list of ID, and want to fetch all records in one query, see [expr IN (value,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: @Naincy yes want to fetch all data for each id

Comment: @Scuzzy ok thank you, will have a look

Comment: you should use a prepare statement approach i'm afraid you could have a sql injection vulnerability here...

Comment: @Scuzzy that is not my goal, i want to use each id in the list of IDS in a where clause " where x.id = (id of the array) and repeat on all ids in the array

Comment: @snap using prepared statement will not help me in this problem, i'm aware of sql injection, but security at the moment is not my highest concern

Comment: @Lalati sql injection is a really big security issue you should take it into account (IMHO)

Comment: @snap we all know it is, and easily applicable, however this is not the subject of the question, thank you for your opinion, taken into consideration

Comment: @Lalati right, just saying. I guess it's allways an important information for all readers which might try to learn from questions and answers and may be even copy paste security issues.

Comment: @Lalati Get the all data for all ids with IN mysql and later with PHP logic can separate the data. Also as per standards its not good to have multiple sql queries or loop mysql query.

Comment: @Naincy ah i see, tried it in the database's sql it returns all the rows, now i can look for a way to seperate them, voting up!

Comment: @Lalati adding as my answer please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the all data for all ids with `IN` mysql and later with PHP logic can separate the data. Also as per standards its not good to have multiple sql queries or loop mysql query.

```
$sql = "SELECT ... and subscriptions.subscription_Id IN (...)";
$resultSql = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSql);
```

After this you can implement any logic in php and get the data as you want.
Ref: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
$claimID = implode(',', $_GET['ids']);
$sql = 'SELECT
          SUM(amount),
          GROUP_CONCAT( subscription_Id ),
          GROUP_CONCAT( amount )
        ... and subscriptions.subscription_Id 
        IN (' . $claimID . ')';
```

You will get the sum of all your amount related the IDS you just recieved.

But beware of **SQL injection** because you are using pure SQL.

Check functions like `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: This works for the sum of ids indeed, but in that way i will lose my ids and get the first id only, however it is helpful and can facilitate some work, and yes pure sql now i m aware of the sql injection, thank you, will vote UP

Comment: You can you GROUP_CONCAT( subscription_Id ) in order to have the list separated by a "," in order to get the list of ids. You can also do GROUP_CONCAT( amout ) to have all amount.